# What is the theory of Electrostatic Polarity Detector (Electric Field Detector) using the FDS8958A Chip?

Tags: transistors

I was studying about the Electrostatic Polarity Detector(Electric Field Detector) made of FDS8958A Chip ([see video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WptwVzK7cK0)).

I wish to understand the physics behind this equipment. It uses an FDS8958A Chip which contains a N-channel and P-channel Enhancement mode power FETs. The circuit is:

[image]

I would like to know how this circuit works and it is able to detect positive and negative charges.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to couple using switch capacitance with small C then clamp with body diode and Miller Capacitance the noise generated by either fast rising or fast falling pulses so it is detecting pretty high AC fields other above the line noise E field threshold so they don't turn on.  This offers no clamp protection for very high Vgs thresholds. Zeners might  add gate capacitance but I think small signal diodes with series 10k resistors should protect it.

If you want to detect DC E-field polarity with a much lower sensitivity, you would have to notch out the 50/60 Hz line noise E-fields. But these noise generators are very high frequency E-fields with low Hz buzz rep rates. (Van den Graff generators)

Nice novelty item like the hundred match stick closing prompt ignited by very high E fields.